# Add asterisk outside <selectonemenu> tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put asterisk outside the box which fields are mandatory and I am not able to get desired result. After some research, I found this code on internet but then it's still not working for me.
This is my HTML code

```
<

div class="add_cdc_info">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{editCdc.selectedMedia}">
                                <f:ajax listener="#{editCdc.changeSubtype}"
                                    render="speciality_selection" />
                                <f:ajax listener="#{editCdc.changeUnit}"
                                    render="speciality_unit" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select Media Channel" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{editCdc.listOfMediaChannels}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
<label class='control-label'>
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="speciality_selection"
                                value="#{editCdc.selectedSubtype}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select Subtype*" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{editCdc.subtypeValues}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
</label>

</div>
```

This is the corresponding css stylesheet

```
.add_cdc_info .control-label:after { 
    color: #d00;
    content: " *";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 8px;
    top:7px;}
```

But then I am not getting desired result. How I can do this?
The asterisk should appear just outside the box as it comes outside required fields.

Comment: this is what u want? : http://jsfiddle.net/wxcde22w/

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery at all?

Comment: @Sina I don't mind using jQuery